# Something not quite right with my array_diff in php

Tags: php

So here is my code from my genetics calculator:

```
// Set up male dominant traits
$maleDom = 'WT';
// Set up male recessive traits
$maleRec = 'ba,b,ec';
// Set up male snow traits
$maleSnow = '';

// Set up female dominant traits
$femaleDom = 'WT';
// Set up female recessive traits
$femaleRec = 'ba,b,mp';
// Set up female snow traits
$femaleSnow = '';

$maleRecArray = explode(',', $maleRec);
$femaleRecArray = explode(',', $femaleRec);

$nonMatchedRecessives = array_diff($maleRecArray, $femaleRecArray);
```

Which throws out `Array ( [2] => ec )`. But you can see that `ec` and `mp` exist in separate arrays. So surely it should be showing `mp` too as it's different to the other array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run it twice, comparing the 2 arrays in reverse order, like this:

```
array_merge(array_diff($maleRecArray, $femaleRecArray), array_diff($femaleRecArray, $maleRecArray));
```

Which spits out:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ec
    [1] => mp
)
```

[<kbd>Example</kbd>](http://www.tehplayground.com/#7iEhZw8MO)

Comment: Oh that makes complete sense! Thank you :D

Comment: To extend this answer, it is because `array_diff()` compares *the elements that exist in array A that don't exist in array B* - hence why you need to diff it both ways. There are questions on this on SO already.

Answer (score 0):

Please check: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

The operational part is:

> Compares array1 against one or more other arrays and returns the
>   values in array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.

EDIT: [To answer your 2nd question] From the hip:

```
$nonMatchedRecessivesMale = array_diff($maleRecArray, $femaleRecArray);
$nonMatchedRecessivesFemale = array_diff($femaleRecArray, $maleRecArray);
```

Comment: Okay, so how can i find the differences in both arrays?

Comment: To get the difference in both arrays, execute the function twice, reversing the arguments the second time, optionally merging the results: `$nonMatchedRecessives = array_merge(array_diff($maleRecArray, $femaleRecArray), array_diff($femaleRecArray, $maleRecArray));`

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer. Read below for what's happening in detail. tldr; `array_diff()` is 1-way check.

```
$fullDiff = array_merge(array_diff($femaleRecArray,$maleRecArray), array_diff($maleRecArray, $femaleRecArray));
```

This is expected behaviour for `array_diff()`.

You get the difference between these two arrays, so either way, `ec` or `mp` are both right.

So this gives you the difference between both arrays:

`array_diff($femaleRecArray,$maleRecArray);` and `array_diff($maleRecArray, $femaleRecArray);`

I just swapped their places.

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "ba"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "b"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "ec"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "ba"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "b"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "mp"
}
array(1) {
  [2]=>
  string(2) "mp"
}
```

Played around with the code [here](http://ideone.com/zr5Iti).